# How Do I Profile the ADO.NET Connection Pool?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, connection-pooling

I'm profiling a ASP.NET web application. I believe it is very database connection intensive (excessive use of the ADO.NET connection pool). **How to I tell w/out debugging how many times it is going to the pool and on average how many connections are available in the pool?** Are there counters that will give me this info in PerfMon or some other tool?

Comment: Did you try searching for counters in perfmon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at ADO.NET performance counters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503.aspx